# Como crear objetos y guardarlos en un arraylist en c#?

Tags: c#, array, arraylist

Necesito hacer un programa que cree x cantidad de usuarios y pida su nombre y apellido. Cada usuario seria un objeto de la clase Empleado. Lo que no entiendo es como hacer para que el que usa el programa genere esos usuarios y los guarde en un arreglo. Como se crean esos objetos si yo no se cuantos usuarios van a meter en el arreglo? Espero ser claro. Muchas gracias. C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parte de los arrays, en C# existen distintas estructuras de datos que podrían ayudarte. En tu caso particular yo me decantaría por las [listas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8). Con ellas no necesitas, por ejemplo, saber cuantos datos quieres guardar.

Son bastante sencillas de utilizar. Puedes agregar datos:

```
List<Empleado> empleados = new List<Empleado>();
Empleado e = new Empleado(idEmpleado);

empleados.Add(e);
```

Puedes hacer búsquedas. Para ello, es buena idea que eches un vistazo a [Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/):

```
empleados.Where(x => x.idEmpleado == 123)
```

Y eliminar:

```
empleados.RemoveAll(x => x.idEmpleado == 123)
```